# Forwarding "ads.txt" for AdSense while using https->https redirect(IIS:URL rewrite)

Tags: iis, adsense, app-ads.txt

My website is hosted on a Microsoft IIS server.
I have created a rule that forward all http requests to https and I am using "URL rewrite".
As explained for example here:
[Link to tutorial](https://aboutssl.org/iis-redirection-http-to-https/)

All the requests are getting forward correctly.
My problem is that AdSense needs the static file "ads.txt" for identification. this file is not being forward and gets blocked and so - my site cannot be verified.
If I check "http://blabla/ads.txt" -> the link is NOT available.
If I check "https://blabla/ads.txt" -> the link is available.

Any ideas?

this is my web.config.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="https redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Add a rule before this redirect rule with `match` pattern set to `ads.txt` and point it to your static file, and stop processing from there.

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you check `http://blabla/ads.txt`? or you can also try to use failed request tracing to get detailed error information.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li , I have added this rule "<rule name="adstxtrule">
           <match url="ads\.txt" />
           <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://blabla/ads.txt"  stopProcessing="true"/>
         </rule>". the same rule that is advised here and I have tried before  https://docs.nitropay.com/en/articles/3620277-redirecting-ads-txt-on-windows-server BUT with the "stopprocessing" that you have recommended. If you want write it as an  answer - I will accept it as so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Lex Li,
(do not add "stopProcessing="true"" to the first rule)
this is the working web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
    <rule name="adstxtrule">
          <match url="ads\.txt" />
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://arbelsolutions.com/ads.txt"/>
        </rule>
    <rule name="https redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"  redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Edit I - following nrod remark, this version also works:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
    <rule name="adstxtrule">
          <match url="http://www.arbelsolutions.com/ads.txt" />
           <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://arbelsolutions.com/ads.txt"/>
        </rule>
    <rule name="https redirect" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                   <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                 </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"  redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: In the `<match url="ads\.txt" />` I was using a full url... only with the filename worked fine.